# Is there a transitive property for undirected graph paths?

Tags: graph-theory

Given an undirected graph G.

Is it always the case, that given vertex **u, v, y** in G, 
If there is a path from **u** to vertex **v** and **v** to **y** then there will be a path from **u** to **y**?

Comment: Isn't that obvious? What makes you worry?

Comment: Certainly true, although I believe that if you're interested in path-connectedness more generally, esp. in infinite graphs, this might be interesting: http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/georgakopoulos/connPathcon.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G$ is undirected, being path-connected is transitive:

If there is a path from $u$ to $v$ and one from $v$ to $y$, there is a path from $u$ to $y$ that passes